# How should the dotted border on clickable images be removed?

Tags: html, css, image

Client does not like the dotted border. I like to leave it there for accessibility reasons. :/

I guess I have to though because the client asked, how would I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: *:focus {
    outline: none;
} // to be perfect ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
a {outline:none;}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
img { border: 0 }
```

to do it.  Put that into your css file or add to the HTML file inside `<style>  </style>`

If they are referring to the dotted border when the image is the active link, then use

```
img, img:active { border: 0 }
```